# pip: force install ignoring dependencies

Tags: python, pip

Is there any way to force install a pip python package ignoring all its dependencies that cannot be satisfied?

(I don't care how "wrong" it is to do so, I just need to do it, any logic and reasoning aside...)

Comment: did you try `pip install --no-deps <LIB>`?

Comment: I'd argue that this is correct way to install production requirements from a lock file produced by tools like pip-tools, where you expect all transitive dependencies to already be resolved.

Comment: A good reason to do so these days is to keep libs in an earlier Docker layer and source install in a later layer. This decreases the time to build Docker images. So it is not "wrong" in that sense.

Answer (score 436, accepted):

pip has a `--no-dependencies` switch. You should use that.

For more information, run `pip install -h`, where you'll see this line:

```
--no-deps, --no-dependencies
                        Ignore package dependencies
```

Comment: how to pass this within a requirements.txt file?

Comment: To run with a requirements.txt, it would be: `pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Anything like this to prevent installing recommended packages like with `apt-get install --no-install-recommends`?

Comment: @Connor there is no equivalent to "recommended packages" in any of the standard Python packaging tools: distutils, setuptools, pip. Setuptools (and pip) has "extras", but they must be explicitly selected and installed by the user.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for a local package. `pip install --no-deps /path/to/package` gives the message "Installing build dependencies" and attempts to install build dependencies.

Comment: @BenCaine try using --no-build-isolation as well, this will turn off the build isolation feature of newer pip versions, which will mean that all build requirements must be present already.

Comment: it does not work for me... stlil installs dependencies: `pip install --no-deps aequilibrae
Collecting aequilibrae
  Using cached aequilibrae-0.7.7.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error`

Comment: Awesome! So this would be suitable for installing from `pip freeze` output, since every required package should already be present?

Answer (score 25):

Try the following:

```
pip install --no-deps <LIB_NAME>
```

or

```
pip install --no-dependencies <LIB_NAME>
```

or

```
pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt
```

or

```
pip install --no-dependencies -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't this ignore *all* dependencies? The OP asked for "all it's dependencies *that cannot be satisfied*". It would be good to still install dependencies if possible, and then just skip ones where some kind of problem occurs.

Answer (score 14):

When I was trying install `librosa` package with `pip` (`pip install librosa`), this error appeared:

```
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I tried to remove `llvmlite`, but `pip uninstall` could not remove it. So, I used capability of `ignore` of `pip` by this code:

```
pip install librosa --ignore-installed llvmlite
```

Indeed, you can use this rule for ignoring a package you don't want to consider:

```
pip install {package you want to install} --ignore-installed {installed package you don't want to consider}
```

Comment: this is not exactly what the op asked for.

according to the man page

-I, --ignore-installed
              Ignore the installed packages (reinstalling instead).


this flag will explicilty reinstall the specified packages, even if they are installed already

Comment: Is there a way to see which packages will be effected before installing? How about telling `pip` to ignore many packages?

Answer (score 2):

I came up to this question looking for a resolution when first package requires `foo-lib<=1.1` and second package requires `foo-lib>=1.0`, so incompatible `foo-lib==1.2` is forcefully installed (as the newest) during the installation of a second package.

The version can be additionally limited with `pip install {second_package} "foo-lib==1.1"`. ([doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/#reduce-the-number-of-versions-pip-is-trying-to-use))