# Installing pip package with dependencies from local directory to local directory without PyPI

Tags: python, pip

Say I've got a Python package called `foo-py`, which is dependent on `lxml`.

I downloaded `foo-py` from PyPI and I want to install `foo-py` to `C:\Users\Me\SomePythonProgram\Modules` without pip attempting to resolve the `lxml` dependency via PyPI.  Again, just to be clear, I want to do this without pip contacting the outside world.  Both `foo-py` and its dependencies exist locally.

I am not using a virtual environment.

How do I accomplish this?  Is this possible?

*Things I've tried:* On Git Bash for Windows, I have tried using `pip -t [target] -e [source] --find-links=file://[target]` to no avail.  pip's options are somewhat nebulous and routinely result in pip dialing out to PyPI.  I have also tried `python setup.py install`, which erroneously throws some error about how the target directory isn't in the `$PYTHONPATH`, even when the `$PYTHONPATH` to `[target]` is explicitly exported. This approach also attempts to create a `/lib/python` directory in [target], which is undesirable and bewildering, as everything other package in the `~/Modules` directory has a flat directory structure.

*Edit*: I could [ignore the dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759761/python-pip-force-install-ignoring-dependencies), but I want to be sure that pip is making sure that `foo-py`'s dependencies are satisfied.

*Edit 2*: There is no `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pip: force install ignoring dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759761/python-pip-force-install-ignoring-dependencies)

Comment: @MegaIng Do I *have to* ignore the dependencies in this case?  Is there an approach where I can get pip to acknowledge that they exist in the target directory?

Comment: Yes. Or you can move the files manually, if they are pure python. But If you want to do something like this, you are probably did something wrong earlier. On a normal system, you shouldn't have to care about dependencies.

Comment: @MegaIng If pip cannot be used to ensure that dependencies are already satisfied when a `-target` is specified, I would like an approach that performs this check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install packages using pip according to the requirements.txt file from a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from-a)

Comment: @phd In reality, the package foo-py does not contain a `requirements.txt` file.  pip is discovering these dependencies without it - I'm not sure of the actual mechanism.

Comment: @alex then just use the package name (strictly speaking, a requirement specifier) instead of `-r requirements.txt`.

Comment: @alex The main options there is not `-r requirements.txt` but `--no-index --find-links`.