# speedml not working with py-xgboost / conda installed py-xgboost is not recognized by pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, xgboost

I have install py-xgboost from anaconda using:

```
conda install py-xgboost
```

where it is shown up when I run

```
conda list
conda env export
```

But from pip it doesnt show up:

```
pip freeze
```

Is there a way to make pip able to 'see' xg-boost that is installed from a conda package?  The reason I need this is because I need speedml which has a dependency on xg-boost and speedml is only available to me from pip (the enterprise anaconda repo do not have speedml).

Thanks!!

Comment: I can't see a way out other than removing the xg-boost conda package and installing it using pip.

Comment: @loudmummer ok thanks it is such a shame that anaconda built this conda package that is readily available to use but it is not 'seen' by pip.  What is the rule behind it?  While most of the conda packages I installed can be recognized by pip why not py-xgboost?  Is it because the conda package name is different to the pip package name?

Comment: It seems xgboost needs to be built from source which is a lot of hassle for me - for one thing github is banned in my workplace.

Comment: Well, I am not sure exactly what happens there, but I think there are some compatibility issues between certain conda packages and their pip counterparts. If you are using conda, it is always recommended to get pip packages only when unavoidable, but this is a very tricky situation you have here.

Comment: @DavidTam where do you get your pip from? The trick often is to install pip from conda and use that. Than pip can see all conda packages. Btw, why did you install `py-xgboost` and not `xgboost`? What is the difference?

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi it is conda pip (output from conda env export:  "- pip=10.0.1=py36_0")

Comment: Did you check that pip from conda is actually picked when you run pip, i.e. what does `which pip` output?

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi yes in fact I created a new conda environment using `conda create -n <env name> python=3.6`.  `which pip` returns `/c/Users/<user_name>/AppData/Local/conda/conda/envs/<env_name>/Scripts/pip` and yes I am on windows

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be solved by using

```
--no-deps
```

[as described in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759761/python-pip-force-install-ignoring-dependencies)
So for example what I need is speedml but it requires xgboost then I create the conda environment, installed py-xgboostm, and run the following in same conda env.:

```
pip install speedml --no-dependencies
```

And afterwards speedml works!