# Continue after single failed required package Installation

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to pip install a python package A. One of the requirements for A is package B which fails to install on Windows and thus fails the entire installation of A.

However, A has lots of useful functionality that doesn't require B. Can I force pip to ignore errors during installation of dependencies?

I could use --no-deps but that would mean I need to find all the other requirements of A and install them individually.

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12759996/4050015

Comment: which package you like to install ? maybe you could download from github and edit the `setup.py`

Comment: Instead of ignoring `B`, maybe just fix whatever the installation error is? Can you add the error log?

Comment: @hoefling to be precise, package `B` is `readline` and it just says that it shouldn't be installed on windows.

Comment: The `readline` package is long obsolete. Can you share the real name of the `A` package?

Comment: @hoefling the package A is company internal.

Comment: If you have access to its sources, I would suggest to replace the dependency with `pyreadline` which has a windows installer. Alternatives are not that good - you can e.g. install a dummy `readline` package without sources to trick `pip` into thinking `readline` is already preinstalled. Run `python -c "from setuptools import setup; setup(name='readline', version='7')" install`, replace version string with the version specifier `A` expects.

Comment: @hoefling I like the dummy approach