# pip installl - skip specific dependencies

Tags: pip, requirements.txt

How can pip skip only one dependency while install all the others.
Using --no-deps, --no-dependencies as answered on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12759996/779570) would not work since it prevents **all**
depencencies.

The reason I need to skip a **single dependency** is due to the fact this dependency is not compatible under my environment (I have a personalized version of this dependency instead)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use a [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) or [`constraints.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files) file to let *pip* know to use your modified version of the dependency. These 2 files have different meanings and different options that they can handle, so depending on your exact needs one or the other might be a better fit. I would recommend using the `constraints.txt` file if possible.

**A.**

```
# requirements.txt
TheDependency --find-links /path/to/dir/containing/modified-dependency
```

```
python -m pip install Something --requirement requirements.txt
```

**B.**

```
# constraints.txt
TheDependency @ /path/to/modified-dependency-1.2.3.whl
```

```
python -m pip install Something --constraint constraints.txt
```