# Install Package Using setup.py and Excluding Dependencies

Tags: python, setup.py

I am interested in running a script that is part of a rather large Python package. The package structure looks something like this:

```
MyApp
|
--setup.py
|
--MyApp
  |
  --foo
  |
  --scripts/some-tiny-script.py
```

`some-tiny-script.py` only relies upon a few simple 3rd-party libs and the MyApp package itself.

I would like to only install the dependencies that `some-tiny-script` requires without installing everything listed in the `install_requires` section of the `setup.py` file. This is because it contains many libraries, some of which are very large. I'm ok with identifying the libraries needed by `some-tiny-script.py` and installing those with pip, but how do I install MyApp without installing everything listed under `install_requires`?

Comment: [Does this answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12759761/315168)?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mikko! I was confused by the overlap between what the `pip install` and `setup.py install` commands do. Here's what I ended up doing:

1. `cd MyApp` (The one containing `setup.py`)
2. `pip install -e --no-deps` This install MyApp. It also posts a lot of warnings but that's ok.
3. Run my script and get errors about missing dependencies
4. Install dependencies individually using `pip`. GOTO 3.
5. Once my script no longer throws errors I'm done :-)

This is an unwieldy process for large scripts or apps but for small scripts it's doable and saves me multiple gigabytes of storage space in my Docker image.