# Installation of Neuraxle package with dependencies conflicts

Tags: pip, package, conflict, neuraxle

Trying to install Neuraxle, I am facing to conflict caused by dependencies:

```
    neuraxle 0.8.1 depends on markupsafe==2.0.1   
    jinja2 3.1.2 depends on MarkupSafe superior or =2.0  
    werkzeug 2.2.2 depends on MarkupSafe superior or =2.1.1.
```

Is it possible to force dependencies configuration files to complete the installation?

Trying to update each package with pip processus manually.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The jinja2 and werkzeug packages are not required to run most features of Neuraxle, only the REST API serving feature.

There is a way to install a library on pip without all of its dependencies. See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12759996/2476920

```
--no-deps, --no-dependencies
                        Ignore package dependencies
```

So you can run pip with a `--no-dependencies` flag.

If you want to manually install the other dependencies, you can find them here: https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle/blob/master/requirements.txt